# How do i tunnel through a keyed ssh login into an svn server not running on a default port?

Tags: ssh, svn, tunneling

I have access to a server via standard ssh, logging in password-less via a key.

On that remote server i can access another server, which has svn on a non-default port, like 174.53.45.6:3456.

I'd like to be able to connect to that svn from my own local machine without having to manually start a putty tunnel process every time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using putty's plink.exe is your friend in that case.  You need to start an ssh connection in order to have the ssh-tunnel created.  On a windows machine, you would have to use a client like putty to do so, but putty's full installer included plink.exe which you can run in a dos-term.

Can't remember the link to the developer's site, but there's also "sshtunnel" the link is here (google'd):
http://www.download32.com/ssh-tunnel-client-i26950.html